# Como sumar cantidades de registros repetidos con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

como puedo hacer para sumar la variable canti_recibidos donde el codigo_reci este repetido de mi tabla recibir_items.

Estoy buscando como hacer para sumar esos valores desde mi consulta.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("conn.php");

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=basededatos", "root", "");


$acliente = $_GET['cliente'];


$limit = '5';
$page = 1;
if($_POST['page'] > 1)
{
  $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
  $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
  $start = 0;
}


$query = "
SELECT * FROM recibir_items WHERE cliente='$acliente'
";

if($_POST['query'] != '')
{
  $query .= '
  AND codigo_reci LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'%"
  ';
}

$query .= 'ORDER BY id_reci DESC ';

$filter_query = $query . 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$total_data = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($filter_query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$total_filter_data = $statement->rowCount();

?>
```

Todo me funciona perfectamente, pero no se como hacer para sumar esa variable por cada código que se repita.

ejemplo:

descripcion     = producto1
codigo_reci     = 999
canti_recibidos = 1

descripcion     = producto2
codigo_reci     = 999
canti_recibidos = 1

En este ejemplo tengo diferente descripción pero es el mismo codigo, entonces el total debe ser cantidad 2

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me seria de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es un arreglo multidimensional validando que codigo_reci sea una llave del arreglo y creando como valor canti_recibidos que almacene y sume la cantidad de veces que encuentre el codigo de recibidos.

Te muestro un pequeño ejemplo.

```html
<pre>

    $data = [
            ["codigo_reci"=>88,"canti_recibidos"=>41587],
            ["codigo_reci"=>88,"canti_recibidos"=>43],
            ["codigo_reci"=>999,"canti_recibidos"=>41587],
            ["codigo_reci"=>88,"canti_recibidos"=>1472],
            ["codigo_reci"=>999,"canti_recibidos"=>516],
            ["codigo_reci"=>88,"canti_recibidos"=>117],
            ["codigo_reci"=>999,"canti_recibidos"=>128],
            ["codigo_reci"=>88,"canti_recibidos"=>66.01],
            ["codigo_reci"=>999,"canti_recibidos"=>235.96],
            ["codigo_reci"=>4,"canti_recibidos"=>330.05]
            ];
    $arrayDatosSumados = [];
    $arrayCodigos = [];
    foreach($data as $campo) {
        if(!in_array($campo['codigo_reci'],$arrayCodigos)) {
            $arrayCodigos[] = $campo['codigo_reci'];
            $arrayDatosSumados[$campo['codigo_reci']]['canti_recibidos'] = $campo['canti_recibidos'];
        } else {
            $arrayDatosSumados[$campo['codigo_reci']]['canti_recibidos'] += $campo['canti_recibidos'];
        }
    }
</pre>
```

- En $data tienes el set de datos que has obtenido de tu consulta.
- Creas dos array $arrayDatosSumados que se utiliza para crear el arreglo multidimencional
- $arrayCodigos para guardar que codigos se han encontrado en tu set de datos para el campo codigo_reci
- Al recorrer tu se de datos con el foreach, se valida que el valor que viene en $campo['codigo_reci'] NO SE ENCUENTRE en el arreglo de codigos $arrayCodigos que cree en el arreglo multidimensional otro arreglo interno con valor de llave el valor de codigo_reci y dentro de este array que almacene el valor de canti_recibida
- De lo contrario que busque en el arreglo interno con el codigo_reci y que sume la cantidad que tiene guardado el arreglo mas el nuevo valor que encontro.

Y tendras como resultado lo siguiente:

```html
<pre>
Array
(
    [88] => Array
        (
            [canti_recibidos] => 43285.01
        )

    [999] => Array
        (
            [canti_recibidos] => 42466.96
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [canti_recibidos] => 330.05
        )

)
</pre>
```

Espero esto solucione tu inconveniente.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu pregunta, aun no he podido implementar tu solución a mi problema, seguiré intentando, muchas gracias.